# How do you set <select> value/option in edit/new template - ExpressJS

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to use a partial to share a _form.html across an new.html and edit.html templates in ExpressJS. The problem is with the `select` tag.

How do you get a select HTML element to have the correct option selected in an edit form? If you use

```
<select value="#{blob.kind || ''}">
```

The `select` doesn't show the option whose value is equal to the `blob.kind`.

Comment: Are you using jade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to do this as follows:

```
select
  each obj in options
    option(value= obj.value, selected=blob.kind === obj.value ? true : false)= 
obj.text
```

Comment: The `selected` attribute is a boolean attribute, meaning it shouldn't have any value assigned to it (even "true" or "false"). Instead its presence or absence determines the value. That's why other answers have a conditional statement.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Answer (score 3):

In order to specify a selected option, a `selected` attribute needs to be added to the `option` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Assuming the `blob.kind` property is a value string, you could write the Jade for your `select` and `option` elements as follows:

```
-
  var options = [
    {value: 'option1', text: 'Option 1'},
    {value: 'option2', text: 'Option 2'},
    {value: 'option3', text: 'Option 3'},
    {value: 'option4', text: 'Option 4'}
  ];

select
  each obj in options
    if (blob.kind === obj.value)
      option(value= obj.value, selected)= obj.text
    else
      option(value= obj.value)= obj.text
```

For future reference, Jade has been [renamed to Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184).

Answer (score 0):

Sean's suggestion is excellent, but his syntax didn't quite work for me. Here's what I ended up with:

```
- const stateOptions = [{value:'AL', text:'Alabama'}, ...]
  select#state(name='state' required)
    each option in stateOptions
      if (option.value === meeting.state) 
        option(value=(option.value) selected) #{option.text}
      else
        option(value=(option.value)) #{option.text}
```